# Laravel - How To Access and Manipulate JSON Array Elements

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5, controller

Can someone teach me how can i access each of the category element in the data array?? PS: I post this JSON using Postman and try to manipulate it in a laravel project controller method.

But i keep on getting this error:

```
ErrorException: Trying to get property &#039;data&#039; of non-object
```

There is no problem with my routes as i have successful using get and post request for other simple process.

I also use Content-Type with application/json header to send this JSON using the Postman software.

My controller method:

```
public function requestStore(Request $request) {

        //
}
```

JSON:

```
{
  "id": "126612213872902",
  "name": "Jack Daniel",
  "likes": {
    "data": [
      {
        "category": "Steakhouse",
        "id": "330668300343348"
      },
      {
        "category": "Steakhouse",
        "id": "793734850733472"
      },
      {
        "category": "Steakhouse",
        "id": "650634241797601"
      },
      {
        "category": "Steakhouse",
        "id": "146621545355340"
      },
      {
        "category": "Italian Restaurant",
        "id": "146805911480"
      },
      {
        "category": "Ice Cream Shop",
        "id": "545851225458015"
      },
      {
        "category": "Fast Food Restaurant",
        "id": "24540959832"
      },
      {
        "category": "Fast Food Restaurant",
        "id": "478890372318431"
      },
      {
        "category": "Fast Food Restaurant",
        "id": "78934590040"
      },
      {
        "category": "Korean Restaurant",
        "id": "553600018012159"
      },
      {
        "category": "Korean Restaurant",
        "id": "388180681558608"
      },
      {
        "category": "Chinese Restaurant",
        "id": "288066224573571"
      },
      {
        "category": "Chinese Restaurant",
        "id": "77730698813"
      },
      {
        "category": "Steakhouse",
        "id": "80555139083"
      },
      {
        "category": "Steakhouse",
        "id": "276973702580"
      },
      {
        "category": "Halal Restaurant",
        "id": "407606596237025"
      },
      {
        "category": "Malaysian Restaurant",
        "id": "337074526415500"
      },
      {
        "category": "Malaysian Restaurant",
        "id": "607366992933940"
      },
      {
        "category": "Malaysian Restaurant",
        "id": "523902944321612"
      },
      {
        "category": "Malaysian Restaurant",
        "id": "194113415406"
      },
      {
        "category": "Malaysian Restaurant",
        "id": "177159752316413"
      },
      {
        "category": "Malaysian Restaurant",
        "id": "705777492887089"
      },
      {
        "category": "Malaysian Restaurant",
        "id": "1545544055681553"
      },
      {
        "category": "Steakhouse",
        "id": "558487800860920"
      },
      {
        "category": "Steakhouse",
        "id": "129509727619"
      }
    ],
    "paging": {
      "cursors": {
        "before": "MzMwNjY4MzAwMzQzMzQ4",
        "after": "MTI5NTA5NzI3NjE5"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're posting raw json through Postman like this **don't forget to set type to JSON**
[image]

Access the data like you would an array instead

```php
Route::post('/test', function () {
    $data = request()->all();
    foreach ($data['likes']['data'] as $key => $value) {
        dd($value['category']);
    }
});
```

Result:
[image]

I hope this helps

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem

Comment: dude, is it possible for me to insert each of the data into db through the loop??

Comment: Of couse, just call the model and pass the data into the create method, but that's a different question

Comment: @CaddyDDZ can u invite me into a room man or can i contact u somewhere? I want to ask about that particular question :))